# How to create a custom POST Action in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a custom POST action for my article object.

In my `routes.rb`, I have set the action in the following way:

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    post 'update_assigned_video'
  end
end
```

In my `articles_controller.rb` I have:

```
def update_assigned_video
  @article = Articles.find(params[:id])
  @video = Video.find(:id => params[:chosenVideo])
  respond_to do |format|
  if !@video.nil?
    @article.video = @video
    format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => t('article.updated')) }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "assign_video" }
  end
end
```

Then in my view I make a form like this:

```
<%= form_for @article, :url => update_assigned_video_article_path(@article) do |f|%>
  [...]
  <%= f.submit t('general.save') %>
```

The view renders (so I think he knows the route). But clicking on the submit button brings the following error message:

```
No route matches "/articles/28/update_assigned_video"
```

`rake routes` knows it also:

```
update_assigned_video_article POST   /articles/:id/update_assigned_video(.:format)    {:action=>"update_assigned_video", :controller=>"articles"}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is this the wrong approach to do this?

Comment: Is it the typo `routes.rb`? `:aricles`?

Comment: Does your `rake routes` display the specified route?

Comment: @alex: The Typo was just here (I corrected it now) | @ Chuck: Yes, it is in the rake routes (I added the output of it to the question)

Comment: Check the rendered source of your view, is the form definitely being POSTed (rather than GET)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `form_for` will do a `PUT` request rather than a `POST` request, because it's acting on an existing object. I would recommend changing the line in your routes file from this:

```
post 'update_assigned_video'
```

To this:

```
put 'update_assigned_video'
```